# what is the compatibility between MSVC and stdlib(ms implementation)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

for example, msvc 14.15.26726, is it compatible with stdlib 14.13.26128?
ps :i'm well understanding that in normal case, we should not play around with different msvc/stdlib combination.

Answer (score 0):

The 'binary compatible' promise for VS 2015 Update 3, VS 2017, and VS 2019 is documented on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017).

The basic summary is this: You can use a mix of C++ static libraries and compiled `.obj` files built with with any mix of these toolsets, with the caveat that the *final link* must be done by the newest version.

You also need to use at runtime the newest version of the REDIST of the toolset mix you are using.

That said, any library or `.obj` using Whole Program Optimization (`/GL`) / Link-Time Code Generation (`/LTCG`) is *not* binary compatible. This is on **by default** for Release configurations so if you want a library to support this scenario you have to disable this optimization.